# mysql fetch_array error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple mysql_fetch_array but for some reasons I get the error

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\get.php on line 5"

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mxc WHERE exp_year > 2009 AND status=0 GROUP BY c_number");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
....
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code ?
thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: From my experience, such errors occur when an invalid query is given. Queries can be invalid for silly reasons such as typo in name of column. You could do a double check on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you have a mysql error. Change your query line to this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mxc WHERE exp_year > 2009 AND status=0 GROUP BY c_number") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

And see what output you get.